# How celery worker manages memory with autoscale option

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery worker that I run with `autoscale` option. I run this with following command:

```
celery -A proj worker -Q pipeline -I proj.apps.pipleine.tasks --autoscale=8,2
```

The tasks of this worker use ml model that is responsible for predicting the language of the documents.

I load this model once in `proj.ml.models` module. Something like

```
predict_language_model = model.load("/path-to-model")
```

Then I import `predict_language_model` in `proj.apps.pipleine.tasks` module. And I use this in my task. It looks like this:

```
from ml.models import predict_language_model
    
@app.task
def process_document_task(doc_id):
    document = get_document_from_database(doc_id)
    predict_language_model.predict(document)
     ...
```

Above task is defined in `proj.apps.pipleine.tasks` module.

I read the docs and it looks like when I use `autoscale` it starts a new process when the load is higher to process each document.

**Does is create a new `predict_language_model` instance in each of this processes? So If I process like 8 documents than I have 8 instances of predict_language_model in memory?**